# Labeling MSSQL-Layer in QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, labeling, sql-server

I am using QGIS 2.14 and have problems with labeling a layer.

My layer is a MSSQL-Layer (from a GIS-Server) and the fieldtype I am using for labeling is a Sting (typename is nvarchar).If the string contains a forward-slash (/), then no label is displayed. Only objects without forward-slash in the labelfield are labeled.

I can use the same layer in QGIS 2.8 without problems on labeling (all object, including forwar-slash, are labeled).

For testing I created a local shp-layer with the fieldtype string (and typname string) and I have no problems on 2.14.

Have anybody an idea what´s going wrong on labeling my MSSQL-Layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to use `eval()`, e.g. `eval('"name"')`

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/14402) which will be fixed in 2.14.1.

Comment: When will 2.14.1 be available?